# make az cli synapse resume/pause fault tolerant

Tags: azure-cli, azure-synapse

In order to save money, I'm using `az synapse sql pool pause` and `az synapse sql pool resume`, so that the Synapse dedicated pool database only turns on to run tests when there is a Pull Request, then shuts down after.

The challenge is that:

- `az synapse sql pool resume` fails is the database is already resumed, and
- `az synapse sql pool pause` fails if the database is already paused

below is an example output of what happens when one of the above situation occurs

```
Command group 'synapse' is in preview and under development.
Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus

Deployment failed.
Correlation ID: 062ea436-f0f0-4c11-a3e4-4df92cdaf6b5.
An unexpected error occured while processing the request.
Tracking ID: 'ba5ce906-5631-42ad-b3f4-a659095bdbe3'

Exited with code exit status 1
```

How can I make this command tolerate the state already being achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how you would resume the database if and only if it were currently paused, then wait for it to be resumed/"Online". requires 3 separate commands...

```sh
state=$(az synapse sql pool show \  
    --name $DB_NAME \
    --resource-group $RG_NAME \
    --workspace-name $WKSPC_NAME \
    --query "status")

if [ "$state" = "Paused" ]; then
  echo "Resuming pool!"
  az synapse sql pool resume
    --name $DB_NAME
    --resource-group $RG_NAME
    --workspace-name $WKSPC_NAME

  az synapse sql pool wait
    --sql-pool-name $DB_NAME
    --resource-group $RG_NAME
    --workspace-name $WKSPC_NAME
    --custom "state==Online" 

fi
```